# How to disable the target for application extension when building in xcode?

Tags: xcode6, ios-app-extension

I am looking a way to disable today extension target to decrease build time everytime while developing for application target.

Comment: I came across this post looking for a way to completely disable widgets without removing them from my code base. If anyone else is looking to do the same, remove the widget/extension target from `Target Dependencies` and `Embed App Extensions`.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

In order to disable building/running the NSExtension you build, you should:

1. Click the project file in the project navigator
2. Click the containing app target (the one you DO want to run)
3. Click `Build Phases` tab
4. Open `Target Dependencies` or `Embed App Extensions`
5. Remove the extension (the one you DON'T want to run)

To bring it back, simply click the `+` sign in the same place and re-add it.

Comment: is there any way to also prevent it from compiling? temporarily

Comment: @CQM Removing the extension from Target Dependencies would prevent it from compiling.

Comment: How can we exclude an app extension for debug scheme?

Comment: In Xcode 15.2 this is called "Embed Foundation Extensions" instead

Answer (score 27):

In Xcode 9 the Extension was stil visible in the Widget List of the phone.
In order to hide totally it I had to remove it from "Embed App Extensions".
The procedure is similar to the one described by nurxyz:

1. Click the project file in the project navigator
2. Click the containing app target (the one you DO want to run)
3. Click Build Phases tab
4. Open **Embed App Extensions**
5. Remove the extension (the one you DON'T want to run)