# Xcode Build scheme configuration without specific extension

Tags: swift, xcode, target

In my project I have a target with 4 schemes and project has 2 extensions including today extension and watch extension.

I want to build some schemes without any extension because I use 2 different signing certificates.

How can I disable extension building in specific scheme?

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27534053

You can un-embed the extension for the target you *do*